# predefined macro for 64 bit systems

Tags: c++, gcc, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have to write a function which searches different directories for different (32/64 bit) machine. 
For example :

```
 //if 64 bit
 Opts.AddPath("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu");

 //if 32 bit
 Opts.AddPath("/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu");
```

Is there a predefined/compiler defined macro that lets me select a particular code.

I am using gcc on Ubuntu machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a macro per se, but how about:

Opts.AddPath((sizeof(void*)==8)?"/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu":"/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu");

Comment: is it guaranteed by the language that sizeof(void*) == 8 on 64 bit machines?

Comment: It doesn't have much to do with the language.  You are writing code that depends on an *implementation detail*.  A directory filled with executables who's sizeof(void*) equals 8.  The language also doesn't guarantee that this directory is present.  Maybe you'll run it on a machine with an entirely different architecture some day, but that directory won't be named "x86_64-linux-gnu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the -D flag to define the constant when you're compiling your code ([link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.6/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options))

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) suggests `__LP64__` and `_LP64`.